# Clicking on a user's name on a list, won't add person's name to div

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets

I have build a basic socket chat program. When people login, their names get added to a list of online users (On the left). When users click on one of the other online users, the name should append to a div on the top. But as you see it displays:

> div class="well">null  (Top right area in the picture).

It seems that the server isn't catching the name of the person on the list.
What am I missing?

Here's a image of what the chat looks like
[image]

Client-side:

```
//Whispering
    $("#people").on('click', '.list-group-item', function(){
      var peopleName = $(this).siblings("span").text();
      var peopleID = $(this).attr("id");
      socket.emit("whispering", peopleID);      
    });

    socket.on("addWhispering", function(id) {
      $(".chatToInfo").empty();
      $(".chatToInfo").append('div class="well">' + id + '</div>');
    });
```

Server-side:

```
var people = {};
socket.on("connection", function(client) {
client.on("join", function(name){
    console.log("Someone joined the chat", name);
    roomID = null;
    people[client.id] = {"name" : name, "room" : roomID};
    sizePeople = _.size(people);
    sizeRooms = _.size(rooms);
    socket.sockets.emit("update-peopleCount", {people: people, count: sizePeople});
    socket.sockets.emit("update-people", {people: people});
    socket.sockets.emit("roomList", {rooms: rooms, count: sizeRooms});
    client.emit("updateToSelf", "You have connected to the server. Join or create room to chat");
    client.broadcast.emit('updateToOthers', name + " is online.");
    clients.push(client); //populate the clients array with the client object
});
    client.on("whispering", function(id) {
    var person = people[id];
    client.emit("addWhispering", person);

    console.log("Whisper caught");
});
```

Comment: Missing `<` on `$(".chatToInfo").append('div class="well">' + id + '</div>');` line before `div`

Comment: Does the server recieve the correct id? May it be a problem with the `people`-array on your server-side?

Comment: I added the missing <. Now it displays 'null'. So I guess it is a problem on the server-side. @kalsowerus I updated my server-side code with the initial function when people connect. Can you see how I should target the correct id?

Comment: Does `$(this).attr("id")` on your client return the correct id?

Comment: it returns null.